# Run GenericFilterBean before Logbook log

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, logbook

I have a filter that adds to MDC a correlationId that is received by my HTTP requests. See example below:

```
@Component
class CorrelationIdFilter : GenericFilterBean() {
    private val log = MyLogger.getLogger(this::class.java)

    override fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        if (request is HttpServletRequest) {
            MDC.put("correlationId", getCorrelationId(request))
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }

    private fun getCorrelationId(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
        val correlationId = request.getHeader("x-correlation-id")
        return correlationId ?: "cid-${UUID.randomUUID()}"
    }
}
```

The problem is that at the moment Logbook logs the request, this filter is still not executed, which results in:

- logbook request log (without correlationId in MDC)
- add correlationId to MDC
- [other logs]..

I'm using Spring Boot and logbook starter
`implementation("org.zalando:logbook-spring-boot-starter:2.14.0")`

What I want to achieve is to have the filter executed prior to logbook log.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need this filter to be invoked in the filter chain earlier than logbook logs the request.

Not sure how it works for Kotlin, but for Java we use @Order annotation on top of the filter class and specifying precedence.

Comment: I have this filter configured with the highest precedence already, but since with logbook starter I don't manually create the filter, I don't know how to set a lower precedence.